# On extended real line, is $(-\infty,+\infty)$ still a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

On real line $(-\infty,+\infty)$ is open as well as closed. On extended real line $[-\infty,+\infty]$, is $(-\infty,+\infty)$ still a closed set? Thank you.

Comment: $(-\infty, +\infty)$ is open set anyway

Comment: What is the limit of $n$ as $n$ tends to infinity?

Comment: The extended real line is homeomorphic to $[-1,1]$. (The function $\tanh$ maps $[-\infty,\infty]$ to $[-1,1]$.) So you question is the same as asking whether $(-1,1)$ is closed in $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complement of $(-\infty,\infty)$ is $\{-\infty,\infty\}$. A finite set is closed (but not open) in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (and the extended real line inherits topological properties from $\mathbb{R}$). Thefore $(-\infty,\infty)$ is not closed, but it is open.

**EDIT:** More directly, a set in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty\}$ is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points. But we can construct many sequences in $(-\infty,\infty)$ whose limit is not in $(-\infty,\infty)$. Sequences like $\{ n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, $\{ x^2 | x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and so on, as others have pointed out.

Comment: Something more is needed, I think. Although it is true that a nonempty finite subset of $\mathbb R$ is closed and not open in the standard topology on ${\mathbb R},$ note that the two-point set $\{-\infty,\infty\}$ is **NOT** a nonempty finite subset of ${\mathbb R}.$

Comment: Well, for starters, we are not dealing just with $\mathbb{R}$, we are dealing with $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$. Further, $\{\pm\infty\}$ is certainly nonempty, so are you arguing that it is not finite? I count only two points there.

Comment: The issue is "subset of", not nonempty or finite.

Comment: I see what you're saying. You disagree with my assertion $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty\}$ that it inherits the topological property that finite, nonempty subsets are closed. But we can assert that in this case, $\{\pm \infty\}$ is closed as every sequence of elements from the subset has a convergent subsequence, i.e. $\{\pm \infty\}$ contains all its limit points.

Comment: Even granting that set is closed. How do you get the "Therefore $(\infty, \infty)$ is not closed" from it? It seems by about the argument that you  do not like on Fly by Night's answer.

Comment: I don't disagree with "*my assertation* $\mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ *that it inherits the topological property ...*", only that it is not supported by what you have written.

Comment: I suppose you're both right in that my answer could use some more detail. Allow me to edit.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Is the complementary set open in the extended line?

Answer (score 1):

The extended line is first-countable, so a set is closed if and only if it contains all the limit of convergent sequences in it. What about $x_n=n$? It is a sequence of elements from $(-\infty,\infty)$, and it is convergent in the extended line. Where does the limit lie?

Answer (score 0):

The extended real line is got by adding the points $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

The complement of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\{-\infty,\infty\}$, which is closed. The complement of $\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Since the complement of a closed set is open, it follows that $\mathbb{R}$ is open.

Comment: OP asked if it was closed, not open.

Comment: @walkar If it's open then it's not closed.

Comment: @FlybyNight this is not true in general.

Comment: @lisyarus But it's true in this case because $\mathbb{R}$ isn't the whole space.

Comment: In general, that is false. In this case it holds because $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ is not separable, but it is disingenuous to assert that.

Comment: @FlybyNight not being the whole space still isn't sufficient. Consider a space with several connected components, for example.

Comment: @lisyarus Is my conclusion wrong? Is my argument wrong?

Comment: @FlybyNight of course it isn't wrong. However, it does not answer the question fully.