# $S_{\alpha}=\{x\, \colon \, F(x)\leq \alpha\}$ is closed while F is l.s.c.

Tags: convex-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Consider $F\colon X\rightarrow (-\infty; \infty]$ and $F$ is l.s.c. Then $S_{\alpha}=\{x\, \colon \, F(x)\leq \alpha\}$ is closed.

Proof: fix $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$. Take a sequance $(x_{n})\subset S_{\alpha}$ that is convergent to some $x\in X$. Since $F$ is l.s.c, we have
$$\lim_{n} F(x_{n})\geq\liminf_{n}F(x_{n})\geq F(x).$$
On the other hand, $\alpha\geq F(x_{n})\Rightarrow\alpha\geq \lim_{n}F(x_{n})\Rightarrow\alpha\geq F(x)$. Hence $x\in S_{\alpha}$. Am I correct? I think that the fact that $\alpha$ may by $\infty$ is not a problem. What is more, if $F$ is additionaly convex, then $S_{\alpha}$ is convex and by the Mazur theorem weakly closed, which finally implies that $F$ is weak l.s.c. I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not sure that $\lim_n F(x_n)$ makes sense but you don't need it. Since, as you observed, $\liminf_{n}F(x_{n})\geq F(x)$ and $\alpha\geq F(x_{n}),\forall n$, you conclude $\alpha\geq\liminf_{n}F(x_{n})\geq F(x)$. I think that $\alpha$ must be in $\mathbb{R}$ because $(-\infty,+\infty)$ [is not closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383207/on-extended-real-line-is-infty-infty-still-a-closed-set) in $(-\infty,+\infty]$. For example if $\alpha=\infty$, $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(-\infty,+\infty]$, $F(x):=x$ is continuous but $S_{\alpha}=\mathbb{R}$ is not closed.

Comment: You're right about the limit - "$\lim F(x_{n})$" may not have any sense.

Comment: Do you think that taking $\alpha < \infty$ may have effect on $F$ being weak l.s.c. ?

Comment: You want to use the fact "closed+convex$\Rightarrow$ weakly closed". To be sure that $S_{\alpha}$ is closed $\alpha$ must be strictly smaller than $\infty$.

Comment: Why you took $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$? I've always seen this statement with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Maybe the reason is to avoid this kind of problems

Comment: What worries me is that $\alpha=\infty$ is now "out", but $F$ may achive $\infty$ and now $S_{\alpha}$ "does not catch $\infty$". I take such $\alpha$ in variational or hemivariational inequalities where commonly used is $I_{K}(x)=0$ if $x \in K$ and $\infty$ otherwise.

Comment: I have no knowledge in hemivariational inequalities, but the result assures you that for $\alpha<0$ the set $S_{\alpha}$ is closed. In general lower semicontinuity gives you no a priori information on the case $\alpha=+\infty$. In this case you need additional informations on your functional